# Problem with route in pagination codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Problem with route in pagination codeigniter
the  pagination It only works if you put the main link of the page

Not Working :

```
/android/page
$route['android/page/(:any)'] = 'android/index/$1';
```

Which works :

```
android/index
```

How can I fix it to do this android/page

Comment: Show us the whole route file and does everything else working fine?

Comment: //android
$route['android'] = 'android/index';
$route['android/create_form'] = 'android/create_form';
$route['android-apps/(:any)'] = 'android/show/$1';
$route['android/download/(:any)'] = 'android/download/$1';
$route['android/cunct'] = 'android/cunct';
$route['android/page/(:any)'] = 'android/index/$1';

Comment: @Redov Kadour Try to write your route directive like this: `$route['android/page/:id'] = 'android/index';` I guess that should helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$route['android/page/(:num)'] = 'android/index/$1';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.